# How to add a constant value to all rows in a data.frame using a For loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to create a simple data.frame that adds the value of '1' to each value inside all rows in my current data.frame using a FOR LOOP.

My current loop is just returning the same values. Is it just a silly mistake on my part?

```
b<-as.data.frame(Base, nrow(length(Base)), ncol(5))
for(i in seq(names(Base))){
  j<-names(Base)[i]
  i + 1
}
b
```

For example, these are the original columns from data.frame `Sales`:

```
Year  A  B  C  D
2010  50 60 70 80
2011  10 44 28 20
2012  65 75 65 89
...
```

And my target is:

```
Year  A  B  C  D
2011  51 61 71 81
2012  11 45 29 21
2013  66 76 66 90
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a few things going wrong here that's probably beyond a simple answer as to why your `for` loop has fallen over. There's a decent discussion of iterating with loops here by Hadley - https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html - which might be worth a read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you. It uses the `mutate_if` function from `dplyr` in the `tidyverse` rather than a for loop, but the logic is the same.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  a = c(1:10),
  b = c(11:20),
  c = c(21:30)
)

df1 <- df %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x) x+1)
```

The first argument will select all numeric columns in your data, then the second argument specifies the function, which in this case is just adding 1.

EDIT:

My initial function would also add 1 to your `year` column, so you may want to do this instead

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  a = c(1:10),
  b = c(11:20),
  c = c(21:30)
)

df1 <- df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-matches("a")), function(x) x+1)
```

Except you'd want to replace `"a"` in the last line with `"year"` in your code.

Comment: Or just `df <- df + 1` if we are avoiding loops